# Why might columns added with migrations not show up in rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I added some columns to a table using rails and rake, but they do not show up in rails admin.  What might be a reason for this?  I am successfully registering new objects using them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to restart the rails server.

Comment: Thank you, was wondering why this wasn't happening in production, just added a fake env var to force the server to restart and now my new db columns are showing.